# Product of Functions of Random Variable

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, functions, expected-value

Given the function
\begin{equation}
G(X, y)=-\int\frac{g(x, y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
where $f(x)$ is a probability density function, $X$ is a random variable and $y$ is a choice variable, and $g(x, y)$ is a continuous function of both arguments, and the expected value
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[g(X, y)]=\int g(x,y)f(x)dx.
\end{equation}
$\textbf{Question}$: What is the product of these two functions
\begin{equation}
G(X, y)\cdot\mathbb{E}[g(X, y)]?
\end{equation}
Is it equal to
\begin{equation}
-\int \frac{[g(x, y)]^2}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
-\int \frac{[g(x, y)]^2}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}[f(x)]^2dx?
\end{equation}

Many thanks

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. You are using the letter $x$ with more than one meaning. It is a good idea to use capital letters for random variables.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks.  I have edited the question to, hopefully, make it clearer.

Comment: In those integrals, you should **not** use capital letters, because the variable of integration is not a random variable. So it should be
$$G(X, y)=-\int\frac{g(x, y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x)\; dx$$
The density of a random variable $X$ is $f(x)$ not $f(X)$: the $x$ here is a variable that stands for an ordinary number, not a random variable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. I have edited the question.  The right-hand side was initially written as with small x but I changed it based on the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as $$-\int\frac{g(x, y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x)dx \int g(x,y)f(x)dx$$
or combine the integrals into a double integral (changing the name of one of the integration variables)
$$ - \int \int \frac{g(x, y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x) g(z,y) f(z)\; dx \; dz$$
But there is no reason why it should be any of your other two integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I have made an error in deriving the function $G(X, y)$, which has lead to this misunderstanding. 

This function comes from a first-order condition:
\begin{equation}
\int g(x, y)f(x)dx+y\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x, y)f(x)dx=0,
\end{equation}
which I rearrange for 
\begin{equation}
G(X, y)\equiv y=-\int \frac{g(x, y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)}f(x)dx.
\end{equation}

Is this approach incorrect in itself?

Comment: Should, instead, 
\begin{equation}
G(X, y)=-\frac{\int g(x,y)f(x)dx}{\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)f(x)dx}=-\frac{\mathbb{E}[G(X, y)]}{\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)f(x)dx},
\end{equation}
which, when multiplied by the expected value of $G(X, y)$, would yield 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\mathbb{E}[G(X, y)]^2}{\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x, y)f(x)dx}?
\end{equation}